# c# Как 30 байтов "\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438" превратить в 10 байтов "\u0430\u0434\u0430\u043d\u0438"?

Tags: c#

Веб сайт прислал это "\\u0430\\u0434\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438"

1 символ - 6 байтов

Понятно, что это Unicode, но как правильно получить отсюда читабельную строку string ?

Чтоб декодировать в utf8 например, нужно как то сделать, чтоб "\u0430" виделся как 1 символ unicode а не 6 символов ANSCII

Comment: У вас два разных вопроса - в заголовке и в теле вопроса. Приведите их к одному.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex.Unescape(unicodeString); - в данном случае достаточно